# Restricting access to module procedures from other module procedures

Tags: fortran, fortran2008

I have recently discovered the new feature of Fortran 2008, i.e., `SUBMODULE`s.

Please have a look at my minimum working example down the question. After compilation, it puts the following on the terminal:

```
 Accessed sub0
 Accessed sub1
 Accessed sub2
```

That is, as it should, module procedures of `sub1` and `sub2` can `CALL` each other and everything is OK.

Because of reasons like code architecture and maintenance, I need to restrict this access somehow. That is, module procedures (`sub1` and `sub2`) be invisible to each other. **Can I do so?**

```
MODULE parent
    PRIVATE
    PUBLIC :: sub0
    INTERFACE
        MODULE SUBROUTINE sub1 ()
        END SUBROUTINE
        MODULE SUBROUTINE sub2 ()
        END SUBROUTINE
    END INTERFACE
    CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE sub0 ()
        PRINT *, 'Accessed sub0'
        CALL sub1 ()
    END SUBROUTINE
END MODULE

SUBMODULE ( parent ) submod1
    CONTAINS
    MODULE PROCEDURE sub1
        PRINT *, 'Accessed sub1'
        CALL sub2 ()
    END SUBROUTINE
END SUBMODULE

SUBMODULE ( parent ) submod2
    CONTAINS
    MODULE PROCEDURE sub2
        PRINT *, 'Accessed sub2'
    END PROCEDURE
END SUBMODULE

PROGRAM driver
    USE parent
    CALL sub0 ()
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Why not just 2 separate modules for the 2 procedures?

Comment: @VladimirF Yes of course. This is exactly what I am doing now. But, I am trying to keep with new modern features of Fortran like `SUBMODULE`. Besides, to my knowledge, something like Code Map in C# is not available in Fortran, So I am afraid of working with huge body of source codes (Debugging, Maintenance, and Development). Tried above-mentioned scheme to simplify the control of `CALL`ing between procedures, but that seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

Both `sub1` and `sub2` are accessed by `sub0`, which means that either (or some combination):

- `sub` and `sub2` have to be known at the same level of the module/submodule hierarchy as `sub0`, as in the example.  The subprograms for `sub1` and `sub2` have to be either at the same level as `sub0` or below, in which case host association makes the knowledge of the `sub1` or `sub2` procedure available to the other procedure.
- `sub1` and `sub2` need to be a public entity of some other two modules.  But in this case the subprogram of `sub1` or `sub2` can always just directly reference the module that defines the other.
- `sub1` and `sub2` are external procedures.  Again, the subprogram of `sub1` or `sub2` can directly access the other external procedure.

Entities in a host can be hidden from child scopes if there is a name in the child scope that shadows the name in the host entity (or by use of the expanded capabilities of the import statement in the F2015 draft standard).  You could put a dummy declaration of something with the same name as the name of the procedure that you want to block out from a particular scope, but this is rather artificial.

Comment: *"sub1 and sub2 need to be a public entity of some other two modules. But in this case the subprogram of sub1 or sub2 can always just directly reference the module that defines the other."* But they don't have to.